# Tibco WSDL work at SOAP UI and failed in Iphone/Android

Tags: tibco

We have a WSDL file. WSDL working at Tibco server and we got the XML as output in soap UI. We have to cosume it in on Iphone/Android development. On making request everytime from code we are getting WSDL in response instaed of XML file. We need XML so that we can use it in our Iphone/Android development.

I am sending the WSDL for further reference. If any issues be revert back to me.The rtf is as follows.

Answer (score 0):

you might have not created concreteWSDL

Answer (score 0):

Without Concrete WSDL, you can't execute the same in SOAP-UI too.....

So that is not the correct response...

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the [SOAPAction HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528)?

Answer (score 0):

I know its a basic type of mistake but such mistakes do happen. Have you checked the endpoint URLs? Can you provide the concrete WSDLs you have used for both SOAP UI and android/iphone? What error do you see when using it on the phone?